# ReflectionException: Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, composer-php, laravel-5.4

Im getting this exception when running `phpunit`. I'm running the latest **Laravel 5.4** with **PHPUnit 5.7.23**

```
ReflectionException: Class config does not exist
/home/vagrant/Code/ProcessingHub-App/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:729
/home/vagrant/Code/ProcessingHub-App/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:608
/home/vagrant/Code/ProcessingHub-App/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:575
/home/vagrant/Code/ProcessingHub-App/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:728
/home/vagrant/Code/ProcessingHub-App/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1172
/home/vagrant/Code/ProcessingHub-App/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/ServiceProvider.php:57
/home/vagrant/Code/ProcessingHub-App/vendor/myvendor/core/src/app/Providers/CoreServiceProvider.php:50
/home/vagrant/Code/ProcessingHub-App/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:574
/home/vagrant/Code/ProcessingHub-App/tests/CreatesApplication.php:18
/home/vagrant/Code/ProcessingHub-App/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:89
/home/vagrant/Code/ProcessingHub-App/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/TestCase.php:66
/home/vagrant/Code/ProcessingHub-App/tests/TestCase.php:27
/home/vagrant/Code/ProcessingHub-App/tests/Unit/PassportTest.php:30
```

As you can see the exception comes from **CoreServiceProvider** this is one of my own ServiceProviders Nothing to weird happening there as you can see here

```
/**
 * Register any package services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->registerEloquentFactoriesFrom(__DIR__.'/../../database/factories');

    $this->mergeConfigFrom(
        __DIR__.'/../../config/fields.php', 'fields'
    );
}
```

contents of **fields.php**:

```
return [];
```

If i outcommend `$this->mergeConfigFrom()` it works like a charm, but the weird thing is i do this in multiple ServiceProviders and in these Classes it is not an issue.

I literally tried everything.

- Running: `composer dump-autoload`
- Running: `php artisan optimize`
- Removing vendor and reinstalling everything
- Debugging everywhere but no usefull info
- Replacing test with basic testExample from laravel didn't work either
- I already replaced my .env with an new simple .env didn't help.

My question is:

Does annyone know how i could fix this.

Comment: Is this related: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8547 ?

Comment: Or check your .env file if there is a value without "" !! see [here](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/99)

Comment: @Devon I have looked at that issue but it doesn't solves my problem. I'm using the `Teardown()` and `setUp()` correctly at least that is what i believe. It worked before fine! And it looks like it breaks on the `$this->mergeConfigFrom()` method.

Comment: @Maraboc thanks, but i already replaced my .env with an new simple .env didn't help.

Comment: Please do this **composer dump-autoload -o**

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd Thanks for the thoughts but if you look at the things i tried you can see that i have already did that.

Comment: @tprj29: Its different from composer dump-autoload

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd thanks for your input. I found the bug was in my CreatesApplication Class. See my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

After I looked more into the \tests directory with a fresh Laravel installation i saw the thing i was staring at for like hours and hours.

The application was trying to **register** the **ServiceProvider** before the app was bootstraped. Sorry for the troubles (It was not my code).

```
namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel;

trait CreatesApplication
{
    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

        $app->make(Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

        $app->register(\StepOrange\Core\Providers\CoreServiceProvider::class);

        return $app;
    }
}
```